# How to use existing library components in my own package in Open Modelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to model Brayton cycle in Open Modelica. I downloaded ThermoPower library and also there are some components available in the Modelica Standard Library. But I am not able to simply drag and drop the components of the existing libraries into my own package for creating brayton cycle.(For ex, drag&drop of Heat exchanger).  I tried doing the same within a class as well.

This is my code:

```
package brayton1 
  
  extends Modelica.Icons.Package; 
          
  extends ThermoPower.PowerPlants.GasTurbine.Examples.GasTurbineSimplified; 
  
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger.HeatExchangerSimulation; 
  
  extends ThermoPower.Gas.Compressor ; 
    
  annotation( 
    Documentation(info = "This package tries to implement the brayton cycle simulation with the help of 4 basic componenets -Source, Sink, Compressor, Turbine. Let's see how far it goes...")); 
end brayton1;
```

These are the errors I am getting:

> [1] 17:23:55 Translation Error
> Cannot instantiate bsr_brayton1 due to class specialization PACKAGE.
>
> [2] 17:23:55 Translation Notification
> [ThermoPower.Gas: 2956:7-2956:63]: From here:
>
> [3] 17:23:55 Translation Error
> [Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger: 74:5-76:35]: Duplicate elements (due to >inherited elements) not identical:
> first element is:  outer .ThermoPower.System system "System wide properties"
> second element is: inner .Modelica.Fluid.System system(energyDynamics = >Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial, use_eps_Re = true)
>
> [4] 17:23:55 Translation Error
> Error occurred while flattening model bsr_brayton1

Is there some mistake in my approach or is the nature of Open Modelica like this only?

Comment: The very first error in the log you showed is saying: Cannot instantiate xyz becaues it is a package. You can only instantiate (and simulate) a model.

Comment: Okay, that is my mistake. But what about other errors? I am not able to use existing libraries' components.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you did, but building up a system from existing components should be absolutely possible, and of course also using drag and drop, and mixing components from libraries (as long as the interfaces are compatible). As this is very basic, I would recommend some introductive tutorial, e.g. this one: http://spoken-tutorial.org/watch/OpenModelica/Introduction+to+OMEdit/English/ or anything from that series: http://spoken-tutorial.org/tutorial-search/?search_foss=OpenModelica

Comment: I have watched Spoken Tutorial series, but even there, I have never seen an example where existing components are used. . Anyway, I am giving it a try. I will tell if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this code:

```
package brayton1 

  extends Modelica.Icons.Package;

  model GasTurbineSimplified
    extends ThermoPower.PowerPlants.GasTurbine.Examples.GasTurbineSimplified;
  end GasTurbineSimplified;

  model HeatExchangerSimulation
    extends Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger.HeatExchangerSimulation;
  end HeatExchangerSimulation;

  model Compressor
    extends ThermoPower.Gas.Compressor;
  end Compressor;

  model myExample
    GasTurbineSimplified gasTurbineSimplified1 annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-72, 38}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  end myExample;

  annotation( 
    Documentation(info = "This package tries to implement the brayton cycle simulation with the help of 4 basic componenets -Source, Sink, Compressor, Turbine. Let's see how far it goes...")); 
end brayton1;
```

Comment: You can't change existing examples, such as HeatExchangerSimulation. But you can copy code of this example in your model, and then change it using drag & drop.